# C++ Condition variable to signal end of detached thread execution stalls

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I have some code which I'm working on where a detached thread is spawned, does some work, and then should wait for a signal from `main()` before sending another signal back to main indicating that the thread has quit.

I'm fairly new to condition variables, however I have worked with some multi thread code before. (Mostly mutexes.)

This is what I tried to implement, but it doesn't behave the way I would have expected. (Likely I misunderstood something.)

The idea behind this is to pass a struct containing two flags to each detached thread. The first flag indicates that `main()` says "it is ok to exit, and drop off the end of the thread function". The second flag is set by the thread itself and signals to `main()` that the thread has indeed exited. (It's just to confirm the signal from `main()` is recieved ok and to send something back.)

```
#include <cstdlib> // std::atoi
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <future>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

struct ThreadStruct
{

    int id;

    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex m;

    int ok_to_exit;
    int exit_confirm;

};



void Pause()
{
    std::cout << "Press enter to continue" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}


void detachedThread(ThreadStruct* threadData)
{
    std::cout << "START: Detached Thread " << threadData->id << std::endl;
    
    // Performs some arbitrary amount of work.
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++ i);

    std::cout << "FINISH: Detached thread " << threadData->id << std::endl;
    
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(threadData->m);
    std::cout << "WAIT: Detached thread " << threadData->id << std::endl;
    threadData->cv.wait(lock, [threadData]{return threadData->ok_to_exit == 1;});
    std::cout << "EXIT: Detached thread " << threadData->id << std::endl;
    threadData->exit_confirm = 1;

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    
    int totalThreadCount = 1;

    ThreadStruct* perThreadData = new ThreadStruct[totalThreadCount];
    std::cout << "Main thread starting " << totalThreadCount << " thread(s)" << std::endl;

    for(int i = totalThreadCount - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        perThreadData[i].id = i;
        perThreadData[i].ok_to_exit = 0;
        perThreadData[i].exit_confirm = 0;
                
        std::thread t(detachedThread, &perThreadData[i]);
        t.detach();
            
    }


    for(int i{0}; i < totalThreadCount; ++i)
    {
        ThreadStruct *threadData = &perThreadData[i];
        
        std::cout << "Waiting for lock - main() thread" << std::endl;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(perThreadData[i].m);
        std::cout << "Lock obtained - main() thread" << std::endl;
        perThreadData[i].cv.wait(lock);

        threadData->ok_to_exit = 1;

        // added after comment from Sergey
        threadData->cv.notify_all(); 

        std::cout << "Done - main() thread" << std::endl;
        
    }

    for(int i{0}; i < totalThreadCount; ++i)
    {
        std::size_t thread_index = i;
        ThreadStruct& threadData = perThreadData[thread_index];
        
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(threadData.m);
        std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl;
        int &exit_confirm = threadData.exit_confirm;
        threadData.cv.wait(lock, [exit_confirm]{return exit_confirm == 1;});
        std::cout << "i=" << i << " finished!" << std::endl;
    }

    Pause();

    return 0;
}
```

This runs to the line:

```
WAIT: Detached thread 0
```

but the detached thread never quits. What have I done wrong?

## Edit: Further experimentation - is this helpful?

I thought it might be helpful to simplify things by removing a step. In the example below, `main()` does not signal *to* the detached thread, it just waits for a signal *from* the detached thread.

But again, this code hangs - after printing `DROP`... This means the detached thread exits ok, but `main()` doesn't know about it.

```
#include <cstdlib> // std::atoi
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <future>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

struct ThreadStruct
{

    int id;

    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex m;

    int ok_to_exit;
    int exit_confirm;

};



void Pause()
{
    std::cout << "Press enter to continue" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}


void detachedThread(ThreadStruct* threadData)
{
    std::cout << "START: Detached Thread " << threadData->id << std::endl;
    
    // Performs some arbitrary amount of work.
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++ i);

    std::cout << "FINISH: Detached thread " << threadData->id << std::endl;
    
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(threadData->m);
    
    std::cout << "EXIT: Detached thread " << threadData->id << std::endl;
    threadData->exit_confirm = 1;

    threadData->cv.notify_all();
    std::cout << "DROP" << std::endl;

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    
    int totalThreadCount = 1;

    ThreadStruct* perThreadData = new ThreadStruct[totalThreadCount];
    std::cout << "Main thread starting " << totalThreadCount << " thread(s)" << std::endl;

    for(int i = totalThreadCount - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        perThreadData[i].id = i;
        perThreadData[i].ok_to_exit = 0;
        perThreadData[i].exit_confirm = 0;
                
        std::thread t(detachedThread, &perThreadData[i]);
        t.detach();
            
    }

    for(int i{0}; i < totalThreadCount; ++i)
    {
        std::size_t thread_index = i;
        ThreadStruct& threadData = perThreadData[thread_index];
        
        std::cout << "Waiting for mutex" << std::endl;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(threadData.m);
        std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl;
        int &exit_confirm = threadData.exit_confirm;
        threadData.cv.wait(lock, [exit_confirm]{return exit_confirm == 1;});
        std::cout << "i=" << i << " finished!" << std::endl;
    }

    Pause();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see no notify calls in the original snippet.

Comment: @SergeyA I've added a line with a comment above it, when I run that code, the program hangs on `WAIT: Detached thread 0`.

Comment: I'm curious, why detach the thread when you want to wait for it to terminate? Sounds like you could `join` instead.

Comment: @AndyG Because "reasons", you know how it is sometimes, someone wants something a certain way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future interest: fixed the origional MWE posted in the question. There was two issues

- not capturing local variable in lambda by reference (see other answer)
- 1 too many `wait()` calls

  ```
    #include <cstdlib> // std::atoi
    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    #include <vector>
    #include <random>
    #include <future>
    #include <condition_variable>
    #include <mutex>

    struct ThreadStruct
    {

        int id;

        std::condition_variable cv;
        std::mutex m;

        int ok_to_exit;
        int exit_confirm;

    };



    void Pause()
    {
        std::cout << "Press enter to continue" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
    }


    void detachedThread(ThreadStruct* threadData)
    {
        std::cout << "START: Detached Thread " << threadData->id << std::endl;

        // Performs some arbitrary amount of work.
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i);

        std::cout << "FINISH: Detached thread " << threadData->id << std::endl;

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(threadData->m);
        std::cout << "WAIT: Detached thread " << threadData->id << std::endl;
        threadData->cv.wait(lock, [&threadData]{return threadData->ok_to_exit == 1;});
        std::cout << "EXIT: Detached thread " << threadData->id << std::endl;
        threadData->exit_confirm = 1;

        threadData->cv.notify_all();
        std::cout << "DROP" << std::endl;

    }

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {

        int totalThreadCount = 1;

        ThreadStruct* perThreadData = new ThreadStruct[totalThreadCount];
        std::cout << "Main thread starting " << totalThreadCount << " thread(s)" << std::endl;

        for (int i = totalThreadCount - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            perThreadData[i].id = i;
            perThreadData[i].ok_to_exit = 0;
            perThreadData[i].exit_confirm = 0;

            std::thread t(detachedThread, &perThreadData[i]);
            t.detach();

        }

        for(int i{0}; i < totalThreadCount; ++ i)
        {
            ThreadStruct *threadData = &perThreadData[i];

            std::cout << "Waiting for lock - main() thread" << std::endl;
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(perThreadData[i].m);
            std::cout << "Lock obtained - main() thread" << std::endl;
            //perThreadData[i].cv.wait(lock, [&threadData]{return threadData->ok_to_exit == 1;});

            std::cout << "Wait complete" << std::endl;
            threadData->ok_to_exit = 1;
            threadData->cv.notify_all();
            std::cout << "Done - main() thread" << std::endl;

        }

        for (int i{ 0 }; i < totalThreadCount; ++i)
        {
            std::size_t thread_index = i;
            ThreadStruct& threadData = perThreadData[thread_index];

            std::cout << "Waiting for mutex" << std::endl;
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(threadData.m);
            std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl;
            int& exit_confirm = threadData.exit_confirm;
            threadData.cv.wait(lock, [&exit_confirm] {return exit_confirm == 1; });
            std::cout << "i=" << i << " finished!" << std::endl;
        }

        Pause();

        return 0;
    }
  ```

Comment: Note that this is missing the `delete[]` I mentioned in my answer (which answered the question why `main()` doesn't know about the changed state in `exit_confirm`).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sounds like another error - what is the issue with `exit_confirm`? Does the condition variable not wait here?

Comment: @TedLyngmo You edited your question significantly. The work you provided was useful, but I had already posted the solution before you went back and edited it. Either answer is useful, if I could have accepted more than one I would have.

Comment: Right, I added some suggestions to the answer but did not change anything regarding the answer itself: Capture by reference (and `delete[]` what you `new[]`).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've still upvoted your answer, so you'll still get the rep for it

Answer (score 3):

Your lambda is capturing *by-value* so it will never see the changes made to `exit_confim`.

Capture *by-reference* instead:

```
int& exit_confirm = threadData.exit_confirm;
threadData.cv.wait(lock, [&exit_confirm] { return exit_confirm == 1; });
//                        ^
//                        | capture by-reference
```

You also need to `delete[]` what you `new[]` so do

```
delete[] ThreadStruct;
```

when you're done with the the `struct`s.

---

I also noticed some heap usage after free but that magically went away when I made some simplifications to the code. I didn't investigate that further.

Some suggestions:

- Move code into the `ThreadStruct` class that deals with `ThreadStruct` member variables and locks. It usually makes it simpler to read and maintain.
- Remove unused variables and headers.
- Don't use `new[]`/`delete[]`. For this example, you could use a `std::vector<ThreadStruct>` instead.
- Don't `detach()` at all - I haven't done anything about that below, but I suggest using `join()` (on attached threads) to do the final synchronization. That's what it's there for.

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

struct ThreadStruct {
    int id;

    // move this function into the ThreadStruct class
    void detachedThread() {
        std::cout << "START: Detached Thread " << id << std::endl;
        // Performs some arbitrary amount of work (optimized away here)
        std::cout << "FINISH: Detached thread " << id << std::endl;

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);

        std::cout << "EXIT: Detached thread " << id << std::endl;
        exit_confirm = 1;

        cv.notify_all();
        std::cout << "DROP" << std::endl;
    }

    // add support functions instead of doing these things in your normal code
    void wait_for_exit_confirm() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        cv.wait(lock, [this] { return exit_confirm == 1; });
    }

    void spawn_detached() {
        std::thread(&ThreadStruct::detachedThread, this).detach();
    }

private:
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex m;

    int exit_confirm = 0;           // initialize
};
```

With the above, `main` becomes a little cleaner:

```
int main() {
    int totalThreadCount = 1;

    std::vector<ThreadStruct> perThreadData(totalThreadCount);

    std::cout << "Main thread starting " << perThreadData.size() << " thread(s)\n";

    int i = 0;
    for(auto& threadData : perThreadData) {
        threadData.id = i++;
        threadData.spawn_detached();
    }

    for(auto& threadData : perThreadData) {
        std::cout << "Waiting for mutex" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "i=" << threadData.id << std::endl;
        threadData.wait_for_exit_confirm();
        std::cout << "i=" << threadData.id << " finished!" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Press enter to continue" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Did I `new[]` anything?

Comment: Yes,`new ThreadStruct[totalThreadCount];`

Comment: Ah ok, but that's not the cause of the issue, presumably? Also I've tried capturing by reference, but it doesn't seem to have made any difference. Does it work on your machine?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Yes, that makes the code continue to the end of the progam. I get a report from `-fsanitize=address` about another problem though (even though I've added `delete[]`). Looking into that now, but that's a separate problem from the `exit_confirm` problem.

Comment: Ok, I've got this working at least. There was a problem where I'd got confused between commenting out/not commenting out some stuff. Thanks this is really helpful

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Great! The problem with supplying such long programs is that it's hard to say when "everything is fixed" though. I guess this fixed the problem you asked about anyway.

Comment: Any thoughts on why the first example doesn't work? Or should I remove that and post a seperate question?

Comment: It's ok, I've solved it - I had too many `wait()` calls

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant It has the same capture _by-value_ issue - but also `perThreadData[i].cv.wait(lock);` doesn't check the condition and may get a spurious wake-up. It's also likely that the main thread never releases the lock long enough for any competing thread to catch it.

Comment: Yes, both of those are problems, I actually missed the second one from my list

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Yeah, it's the hardest one to spot i.m.o. The spurious wake-up may also be hard to spot for someone used to other types of threads not having spurious wake-up:s for sure